# What causes Python's __main__ to disappear when embedding with Boost.Python

Tags: c++, boost-python

I'm embedding Python in a C++ app. I want to define a function `V` in the main module which takes a string and returns an instance of a class `A`.

The problem is that `A` needs some data available in the instance of the class embedding Python, passed in the example as `_env` - so I thought I could use def(...) to define `V` in the method, using a lambda to capture the data required.

However, when I do that, I end up getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'` when I try to get the dictionary for the main module.

Without the call to boost's def(...), I'm able to get and add to the main module.

Is there something I'm doing wrong that causes `__main__` to go missing and produce a None when I try to access it? Any recommendations on how else to achieve this?

```
 void B::processRequest(Ptr<protocol::Message> msg, const std::function<void(const std::string &)> &send) {      
      try {
        //make my_module module available to python
        PyImport_AppendInittab("my_module", &initmy_module);
        //
        Py_Initialize();
        //get the main module
        py::object main_module((py::handle<>(py::borrowed(PyImport_AddModule("__main__")))));
        py::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
        py::object my_moduleNamespace((py::handle<>(PyImport_ImportModule("my_module"))));
        //add the module to the main namespace
        main_namespace["my_module"] = my_moduleNamespace;
//add attribute to namespace
//        main_namespace["V"] = py::ptr(this);
        auto AFn([this](std::string label) { return ptr<A>(_env, label); });
        typedef boost::mpl::vector<Ptr<A>, std::string> AFnSig;
        const auto policies = py::default_call_policies();
        py::def("V", boost::python::make_function(AFn, policies, AFnSig()));

        py::handle<> ignored((PyRun_String((*msg->action).c_str(), Py_file_input, main_namespace.ptr(), main_namespace.ptr())));
      } catch (py::error_already_set) {
        PyErr_Print();
      }
      Py_Finalize();
    }
```

The only thing I could think of to work around this was to make `B` callable defining `operator(std::stirng)` but that doesn't work because I have two other functions which need `_env` and one of them as the same signature as `V` so there'd be no way to distinguish between the calls as far as I can see.

**EDIT**:
Changed title to try to make it clearer as to what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that `__main__` is disappearing; the problem is that `V` method was never defined within the scope of `__main__`.  The [`python::def()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/def.html#introduction) function only operates on the current [`python::scope`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/scope.html#introduction):

> `def()` is the function which can be used to expose C++ functions and callable objects as Python functions in the current `scope`.

To resolve this, one can either assign a Python callable object directly into the Python namespace:

```cpp
namespace python = boost::python;
python::object main = python::import("__main__");
python::object main_namespace = main.attr("__dict__");
main_namespace["V"] = python::make_function(...);
```

or set the current scope to `__main__`, then expose the Python callable object via `def()`:

```cpp
namespace python = boost::python;
python::object main = python::import("__main__");
python::object main_namespace = main.attr("__dict__");
python::scope main_scope(main);
python::def("V", python::make_function(...)); // defined in __main__
```

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/420f1cd4429ee25e) this:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main()
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  try
  {
    Py_Initialize(); // Start interpreter.

    // Create the __main__ module.
    python::object main = python::import("__main__");
    python::object main_namespace = main.attr("__dict__");

    // >>> def func1(): return 100
    main_namespace["func1"] = python::make_function(
        []() { return 100; },
        python::default_call_policies(),
        boost::mpl::vector<int>());

    // >>> def func2(): return 100
    {
      // Set __main__.__dict__ as current scope.
      python::scope main_scope(main);

      // def will define in current scope.
      python::def("func2", python::make_function(
        []() { return 200; },
        python::default_call_policies(),
        boost::mpl::vector<int>())
      );
    }

    // Execute func1 and func2 via a python string.
    python::exec(
        "print dir()\n"    
        "assert(100 == func1())\n"
        "assert(200 == func2())\n"
      , main_namespace
    );
  }
  catch (const python::error_already_set&)
  {
    PyErr_Print();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'func1', 'func2']
```

---

Also, you may need change the lifetime of the interpreter or not use Boost.Python.  The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/embedding.html#embedding.getting_started) warns that [`Py_Finalize`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.Py_Finalize) should not be invoked:

> Note that at this time you must not call `Py_Finalize()` to stop the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Can't seem to find a way to do it with bp. So I came up with defining the functions I want in the namespace using plain python and registering the environment object that the python function uses. So writing a python wrapper around the C++ API I'm able to create.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE (my_module) {
  //env is now exposed to the user but can't be constructed and none of its methods are exposed so it's not so bad. Just the symbol exists.
  py::class_<Ptr<Environment>>("Environment", py::no_init);
  py::class_<A>("A", py::init<const Ptr<Environment>, std::string>()); 
}

void B::processRequest(Ptr<protocol::Message> msg, const std::function<void(const std::string &)> &send) {      
      try {
        //make my_module module available to python
        PyImport_AppendInittab("my_module", &initmy_module);
        //
        Py_Initialize();
        //get the main module
        py::object main_module((py::handle<>(py::borrowed(PyImport_AddModule("__main__")))));
        py::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
        py::object my_moduleNamespace((py::handle<>(PyImport_ImportModule("my_module"))));
        //add the module to the main namespace
        main_namespace["my_module"] = my_moduleNamespace;


        my_moduleNamespace.attr("environment") = _env; 
        //HERE - provide the API I want using a native Python function
        py::handle<> envRun((PyRun_String("def V(label):\n  return my_module.A(my_module.environment,label)", Py_file_input, main_namespace.ptr(), main_namespace.ptr())));

        py::handle<> ignored((PyRun_String((*msg->action).c_str(), Py_file_input, main_namespace.ptr(), main_namespace.ptr())));
      } catch (py::error_already_set) {
        PyErr_Print();
      }
      Py_Finalize();
    }
```